# MongoDB не вставляет второй документ в коллекцию

Tags: mongodb

Вставляю первый документ командой db.collection.insert({name:"String"})-вставляется.
При попытке добавить второй, получаю: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: db.collection.$**primary_key** dup key: { : null }'

Пробовал удалить базу и создать новую - тот же результат.

Windows 7 x32, MongoDB 3.2.20

Comment: для вставки нескольких документов необходимо использовать метод `insertMany` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#db.collection.insertMany

Comment: Их можно и по одному вставлять. Не получилось - "write error at item 0 in bulk operation"

Comment: Пробовал так: db.collection.insertMany([{name:"Строка 1"}, {name:"Строка 2"}])